# How can I decrease Autosave frequency?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

ATS saves automatically too much! There are too many saved files that I must delete individually. [I don't know how to delete them concurrently](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/351386/231589).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to change the autosave frequency on either ATS or ETS2 as of 1.35.

I checked the game configuration, user/profile settings and internal game files, was unable to find anything.

Please note that some people say that the autosave frequency can be changed on `def/editor_data.sii`, but it has been [confirmed by a SCS developer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/227300/discussions/1/541906348058544583/#c620712364045408516) that this is has nothing to do with it:

> The editor_data.sii file has nothing to do with interval of in-game autosaves which can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Even now with 1.36, this option hasn't been added, and this is pretty annoying. Autosaves take some data spaces, and there are pretty easy to find.

Open the File Explorer and go to `Documents\American Truck Simulator\profiles` (or `Documents\Euro Truck Simulator 2\profiles` for ETS2). You would find a unique folder that represent your profile name in hexadecimal. Go inside and go into `save` folder.

Here you can find **all** your save folder, manual and auto saves. Before removing them, just move them all in another place and try to launch ATS → if the game works without any new issue, you can delete them all, and enjoy a free space done.

[This Steam Community discussion](https://steamcommunity.com/app/227300/discussions/0/1679189548067094731) is related.